# 2nd order IIR filter, coefficients for a butterworth bandpass (EQ)?

Tags: objective-c, audio, signal-processing, core-audio, accelerate-framework

**Important update:** I already figured out the answers and put them in this simple open-source library: http://bartolsthoorn.github.com/NVDSP/ Check it out, it will probably save you quite some time if you're having trouble with audio filters in IOS!

^

I have created a (realtime) audio buffer (`float *data`) that holds a few `sin(theta)` waves with different frequencies.

The code below shows how I created my buffer, and I've tried to do a bandpass filter but it just turns the signals to noise/blips:

```
    // Multiple signal generator
__block float *phases = nil;
[audioManager setOutputBlock:^(float *data, UInt32 numFrames, UInt32 numChannels)
{
    float samplingRate = audioManager.samplingRate;
    NSUInteger activeSignalCount = [tones count];

    // Initialize phases
    if (phases == nil) {
        phases = new float[10];
        for(int z = 0; z <= 10; z++) {
            phases[z] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    // Multiple signals
    NSEnumerator * enumerator = [tones objectEnumerator];
    id frequency;
    UInt32 c = 0;
    while(frequency = [enumerator nextObject])
    {
        for (int i=0; i < numFrames; ++i)
        {
            for (int iChannel = 0; iChannel < numChannels; ++iChannel) 
            {
                float theta = phases[c] * M_PI * 2;
                if (c == 0) {
                    data[i*numChannels + iChannel] = sin(theta);
                } else {
                    data[i*numChannels + iChannel] = data[i*numChannels + iChannel] + sin(theta);
                }
            }
            phases[c] += 1.0 / (samplingRate / [frequency floatValue]);
            if (phases[c] > 1.0) phases[c] = -1;
        }
        c++;
    }

    // Normalize data with active signal count
    float signalMulti = 1.0 / (float(activeSignalCount) * (sqrt(2.0)));
    vDSP_vsmul(data, 1, &signalMulti, data, 1, numFrames*numChannels);


    // Apply master volume
    float volume = masterVolumeSlider.value;
    vDSP_vsmul(data, 1, &volume, data, 1, numFrames*numChannels);


    if (fxSwitch.isOn) {
        // H(s) = (s/Q) / (s^2 + s/Q + 1)
        // http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt
        // BW 2.0  Q 0.667
        // http://www.rane.com/note170.html
        //The order of the coefficients are, B1, B2, A1, A2, B0.
        float Fs = samplingRate;

        float omega = 2*M_PI*Fs; // w0 = 2*pi*f0/Fs

        float Q = 0.50f;
        float alpha = sin(omega)/(2*Q); // sin(w0)/(2*Q)

        // Through H
        for (int i=0; i < numFrames; ++i)
        {
            for (int iChannel = 0; iChannel < numChannels; ++iChannel) 
            {
                data[i*numChannels + iChannel] = (data[i*numChannels + iChannel]/Q) / (pow(data[i*numChannels + iChannel],2) + data[i*numChannels + iChannel]/Q + 1);
            }
        }

        float b0 = alpha;
        float b1 = 0;
        float b2 = -alpha;
        float a0 = 1 + alpha;
        float a1 = -2*cos(omega);
        float a2 = 1 - alpha;

        float *coefficients = (float *) calloc(5, sizeof(float));


        coefficients[0] = b1;
        coefficients[1] = b2;
        coefficients[2] = a1;
        coefficients[3] = a2;
        coefficients[3] = b0;

        vDSP_deq22(data, 2, coefficients, data, 2, numFrames);

        free(coefficients);
    }

    // Measure dB
    [self measureDB:data:numFrames:numChannels];
 }];
```

My aim is to make a 10-band EQ for this buffer, using `vDSP_deq22`, the syntax of the method is: 
`vDSP_deq22(<float *vDSP_A>, <vDSP_Stride vDSP_I>, <float *vDSP_B>, <float *vDSP_C>, <vDSP_Stride vDSP_K>, <vDSP_Length __vDSP_N>)`
See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/vDSP_deq22

Arguments:

```
float *vDSP_A is the input data
float *vDSP_B are 5 filter coefficients
float *vDSP_C is the output data
```

I have to make 10 filters (10 times `vDSP_deq22`). Then I set the gain for every band and combine them back together. But what coefficients do I feed every filter? I know `vDSP_deq22` is a 2nd order (butterworth) IIR filter, but how do I turn this into a bandpass?

Now I have three questions:

a) Do I have to de-interleave and interleave the audio buffer? I know setting stride to 2 just filters on channel but how I filter the other, stride 1 will process both channels as one.

b) Do I have to transform/process the buffer before it enters the `vDSP_deq22` method? If so, do I also have to transform it back to normal?

c) What values of the coefficients should I set to the 10 `vDSP_deq22`s?

I've been trying for days now but I haven't been able to figure this on out, please help me out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `omega` value need to be normalised, i.e. expressed as a fraction of Fs - it looks like you left out the `f0` when you calculated `omega`, which will make `alpha` wrong too:

```
    float omega = 2*M_PI*Fs; // w0 = 2*pi*f0/Fs
```

should probably be:

```
    float omega = 2*M_PI*f0/Fs; // w0 = 2*pi*f0/Fs
```

where f0 is the centre frequency in Hz.

For your 10 band equaliser you'll need to pick 10 values of f0, spaced logarithmically, e.g. 25 Hz, 50 Hz, 100 Hz, 200 Hz, 400 Hz, 800 Hz, 1.6 kHz, 3.2 kHz, 6.4 kHz, 12.8 kHz.

Comment: Thank you, and what value of Q should I set to cover all the frequencies? (Q refers to the width of the band I think?) And do you think I've calculated the a0..a2 and b0..b2 values correctly for a bandpass?

Comment: If you're going to use octave spacing for f0 as above then I guess you need a Q of around 2 o so. The other calculations look OK. Tip: get one filter working first, with a nominal f0, e.g. 400 Hz, and then move on to the full filter bank.

Comment: Thank you, I've also decided to go for peaking (parametric) EQ instead of bandpasses, and I think I got it figured out now. Thanks!

Comment: Also, running every sample through `H(s) = (s/Q) / (s^2 + s/Q + 1)` isn't necessary I think? (It doesn't make sense either, just guessed it to be required) The `omega` value is already normalised.

Comment: Hmm I don't get why coefficients that are actually scaling the amplitude basically can really form a bandpass, maybe you _have_ to transform the samples before doing IIR?

Comment: The H(s) formula is just the Laplace transform of the Butterworth filter in the analogue domain - it's just there for reference purposes, i.e. you don't need to implement it.

Comment: The biquad IIR filter that you're using when you call vDSP_deq22 is a 2 pole, 2 zero, recursive filter with two delay elements. Simple explanation: by multiplying the various (delayed) terms within the filter by the various coefficients and summing them you get a filter which passes some frequencies and rejects others. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_biquad_filter

Comment: Thanks, your explanation really helps! So that means vDSP_deq22 is also capable of doing peaking/parametric EQ by setting the coefficients to do so. I think it's strange that apple didn't mention the order of the coefficients in vDSP_deq22, according to a japanese site it is B1, B2, A1, A2, B0. (A0 is 1 I guess?) I expected the method (vDSP_deq22) to take all six coefficients just in order (a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2)

Comment: Yes, you can do any kind of filter that can be implemented with a biquad IIR - you just need to supply the right coefficients. Unfortunately I don't know much about vDSP_deq22 specifically and like you I don't see any documentation as to the order of the coefficients. You can work it out empirically by setting all but one coefficient to zero, but that would be tedious.